# Calculate if line, defined by 2 coordinates, intersects circle

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates

I am trying to get a function to calculate if a line, that is defined by 2 coordinates, intersects a circle, defined by a coordinate and a radius. I previously used these 2 functions

```
getLineEquation(point1, point2) {
    var lineObj = {
        gradient: (point1.latitude - point2.latitude) / (point1.longitude - point2.longitude)
    };

    lineObj.yIntercept = point1.latitude - lineObj.gradient * point1.longitude;

    return lineObj;
}

checkIntercept(y, m, circle) {
    // y: y intercept of line
    // m: gradient of line

    // get a,b,c values
    var a = 1 + (m * m);
    var b = -circle.longitude * 2 + (m * (y - circle.latitude)) * 2;
    var c = (circle.longitude * circle.longitude) + ((y - circle.latitude)* (y - circle.latitude)) - (circle.range * circle.range);

    // get discriminant
    var d = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;
    if (d >= 0) {
        // insert into quadratic formula
        var intersections = [
            (-b + Math.sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a),
            (-b - Math.sqrt((b * b) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
        ];
        if (d == 0) {
            // only 1 intersection
            return [intersections[0]];
        }
        return intersections;
    }
    // no intersection
    return false;
}
```

but this didn't work as it converted the 2 points into an infinite line, which I don't want as it would return false readings for circles that aren't actually between the 2 points.

How could I fix these functions to make the calculation into a finite line?

Comment: wait, context. Are we talking planar geometry, or are we talking on a sphere, because there two points don't define a line but an infinity of possible circles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach.

- If one of the two vertices is inside the circle, and the other is outside, then there will be an intersection. (This means two distance calculations.)
- If both vertices lie inside the circle, there is no intersection.
- If the first two steps weren't decisive, find s, the [projection](https://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/classes/visual/03s/hw/h2/math.pdf) of the circle center to the line (p,q).

  - If the distance of s to the circle center is larger than the radius, there is no intersection.
  - Otherwise, if s is between a and b (so s_x between p_x and q_x, and also s_y between p_y and q_y, to include the case of horizontal and vertical edges), then there is an intersection, otherwise not.

To project a point on a line, you basically make a line equation in the form `(px,py) + t * (dx,dy)` with `dx = qx - px` and `dy = qy - py` for two points `(px,py)` and `(qx,qy)`. The perpendicular line through a point `(cx,cy)` is then `(cx,cy) + t * (-dy,dx)`. Setting both equations equal finds the intersection.

Or, if you prefer straight formulas:

```
sx = (d*px + (px - qx)*((cx - px)*(px - qx) + (cy - py)*(py - qy)))/d
sy = (d*py + (py - qy)*((cx - px)*(px - qx) + (cy - py)*(py - qy)))/d
   with
d = (px - qx)^2 + (py - qy)^2
```

Comment: Did you succeed to get it working in your situation?